# php curl xampp extension "curl" must be loaded

Tags: php, curl, xampp

i am facing PHP extension "curl" must be loaded. error while insatalling the magento in xampp.
i have make all change in php.ini file, but the error is still showing
please tell me the another way to handle this error
thanx in advance

Comment: Have you installed curl?

Comment: Have you installed CURL? Have you added its extension in ini file?

Comment: how to install the curl in xampp

Comment: Did you restart the apache server after making the edits to php.ini?

Comment: yes sir i have restarted the xampp..

Comment: What does phpinfo(); says about curl?

Comment: Also what does php_errors say about curl?